# Fastest way to pop N items from a large dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, dictionary, optimization

I have a large dict `src` (up to 1M items) and I would like to take N (typical values would be N=10K-20K) items, store them in a new dict `dst` and leave only the remaining items in `src`. It doesn't matter which N items are taken. I'm looking for the fastest way to do it on Python 3.6 or 3.7.

Fastest approach I've found so far:

```
src = {i: i ** 3 for i in range(1000000)}

# Taking items 1 by 1 (~0.0059s)
dst = {}
while len(dst) < 20000:
    item = src.popitem()
    dst[item[0]] = item[1]
```

Is there anything better? Even a marginal gain would be good.

Comment: Why is this code optimalisation question not transferred to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/? (I did get this question in an audit and it was apparantly kept om main SO site)???

Comment: @ZF007 optimalisation -> optimization. Separately from that, it's here because there's a clear question with a clear answer that is more about the language than my code in particular. To quote a member with a lot of points:

Stack Overflow is the place for specific questions about programming. If it is specific - as in, about a particular function, language element, algorithm, etc., and by that I don't mean "about your specific program" but about a specific element in your program that is 'specific' in the context of programming, not in the context of a program - then it's fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a bit faster still:

```
from itertools import islice
def method_4(d):
    result = dict(islice(d.items(), 20000))
    for k in result: del d[k]
    return result
```

Compared to other versions, using Netwave's testcase:

```
Method 1:  0.004459443036466837  # original
Method 2:  0.0034434819826856256 # Netwave
Method 3:  0.002602717955596745  # chepner
Method 4:  0.001974945073015988  # this answer
```

The extra speedup seems to come from avoiding transitions between C and Python functions. From disassembly we can note that the `dict` instantiation happens on C side, with only 3 function calls from Python. The loop uses `DELETE_SUBSCR` opcode instead of needing a function call:

```
>>> dis.dis(method_4)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (dict)
              2 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (islice)
              4 LOAD_FAST                0 (d)
              6 LOAD_ATTR                2 (items)
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (20000)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 STORE_FAST               1 (result)

  3          18 SETUP_LOOP              18 (to 38)
             20 LOAD_FAST                1 (result)
             22 GET_ITER
        >>   24 FOR_ITER                10 (to 36)
             26 STORE_FAST               2 (k)
             28 LOAD_FAST                0 (d)
             30 LOAD_FAST                2 (k)
             32 DELETE_SUBSCR
             34 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           24
        >>   36 POP_BLOCK

  4     >>   38 LOAD_FAST                1 (result)
             40 RETURN_VALUE
```

Compared with the iterator in `method_2`:

```
>>> dis.dis(d.popitem() for _ in range(20000))
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    2 FOR_ITER                14 (to 18)
              4 STORE_FAST               1 (_)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (d)
              8 LOAD_ATTR                1 (popitem)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             12 YIELD_VALUE
             14 POP_TOP
             16 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            2
        >>   18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

which needs a Python to C function call for each item.

Comment: I was researching this! what a sync!

Comment: @Netwave Do you think this should now be the accepted answer?

Comment: @IvailoKaramanolev, yes, we were searching for the fastest, and indeed this on is.

Answer (score 19):

A simple comprehension inside `dict` will do:

```
dict(src.popitem() for _ in range(20000))
```

Here you have the [timing tests](https://repl.it/repls/RoastedEmbarrassedSoftwaresuite)

```
setup = """
src = {i: i ** 3 for i in range(1000000)}

def method_1(d):
  dst = {}
  while len(dst) < 20000:
      item = d.popitem()
      dst[item[0]] = item[1]
  return dst

def method_2(d):
  return dict(d.popitem() for _ in range(20000))
"""
import timeit
print("Method 1: ", timeit.timeit('method_1(src)', setup=setup, number=1))

print("Method 2: ", timeit.timeit('method_2(src)', setup=setup, number=1))
```

Results:

```
Method 1:  0.007701821999944514
Method 2:  0.004668198998842854
```

Comment: Good one! I'll wait a bit and if there's no faster solution, I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Hopefully next moderator @Jean-FrançoisFabre ;)

Comment: I doubt there is a faster solution in python. And thanks.

Comment: Are the results similar for greater numbers of repetitions?

Comment: for my solution, at least, I've upped all 10 times and it's still faster. The key is to make the shorter code possible and rely on native functions.

Comment: @snakecharmerb This continues to be the fastest solution when popping 100K or 500K items according to my tests.

Comment: to pop _all_ the items, of course, the fastest is to use the original dict :) jokes aside, past half the elements, it's better to use the original dictionary instead and pop `len-nb_values_to_pop`

Comment: You can shave a little more time off by saving the bound method first. `f = d.popitem; return dict(f() for _ in range(20000))`.

Comment: Using `itertools.islice` and `itertools.repeat` is even a little faster still: `dict(f() for f in islice(repeat(d.popitem), 20000))`.

Answer (score 3):

I found this approach slightly faster (-10% speed) using dictionary comprehension that consumes a loop using `range` that yields & unpacks the keys & values

```
dst = {key:value for key,value in (src.popitem() for _ in range(20000))}
```

on my machine:

```
your code: 0.00899505615234375
my code:   0.007996797561645508
```

so about 12% faster, not bad but not as good as not unpacking like [Netwave simpler answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55199446/6451573)

This approach can be useful if you want to transform the keys or values in the process.